# Parse results from mongoDB Query into HTML Table

Tags: html, mongodb

I would like to take the raw data i am receiving from a mongoDB query into a table only using select data from each document that is returned from the query.

RAW data as seen directly on the html page after being retrieved with under $search.

```
array(3) { ["_id"]=> int(100000005) ["dclass"]=> string(15) "Distributed" ["fields"]=> array(114) { ["Name"]=> array(1) { ["_0"]=> string(7) "Testing" } ["NameState"]=> array(1) { ["_0"]=> string(7) "PENDING" }
```

The data i need into the table is the Name and the _id

here is what i currently have.

```
            foreach ($SEARCH as $row) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
             echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name filed is nested. Try this.

```
<?php

foreach ($SEARCH as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fields']['Name']['_0'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```